# How to pass data to Native module from React Native when the app is getting destroyed by the user

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I can get the state of the app using AppState but currently it supports only for Foreground and Background but not when the app is completely destroyed.

Is there anyway I can find an event when the app is getting killed? I believe, I could pass some data as arguments to Native Modules when that event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppState along with Component hooks like **componentWillUnmount** in order to know when user is about to close your app, because currently there is no thing to tell you that the will be closed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but as I have many components/screens in my app, componentWillUnmount happens very often. I am looking for a solution like EventListener in RN to do something when the app is getting destroyed. I just want to pass a piece of data to my native module(Estimote beacon module) when the app is getting killed by the user.

Comment: @Sudharsan Any luck so far?